# I want to use OverridependingTransition in fragment but I am getting an error

Tags: java, android

Here is my code

```
med=(LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.second);
med.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i= new Intent(getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("table_name","questCompFunda");

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your error and what you are trying to do

Comment: You are launching here activity but you mentioned you are finding error in Fragment.

Comment: If you want help with an error, post the error.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to use

`overridePendingTransition` in a **fragment**

So the correct way would be,

```
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

**Edit:**

> Launching an activity from cardview

```
cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   getActivity(). overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to launch a new activity by clicking on cardview in fragment. Can you plz help me?